# Can I call a __device__ function from a CUDA kernel function?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to call two device functions from a CUDA Kernel function:

edit: to avoid confusion that  the function definitions are on different file as the kernel definition, i provided the full code:

```
Complete code:



#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;


#define POLYNOMIAL 0x04C11DB7L //Standard CRC-32 polynomial
#define M 62352 //Number of bits in the bloom filter
#define K 4  //Number of bits set per mapping in filter

typedef unsigned short int word16;
typedef unsigned int word32;

__device__ static word32 CrcTable[256]; //Table of 8-bit CRC32 remainders
__device__ char BFilter[M / 8];         //Bloom filter array of M/8 bytes
word32 NumBytes;                //Number of bytes in Bloom filter

void gen_crc_table(void);
__device__ word32 update_crc(word32 crc_accum, const char *data_ptr, word32 data_size);
__device__ void mapBloom(word32 hash);          
__device__ word32 crc32;
__device__ int retCode; 

__global__ void mapBloomKernel(const char* d_wordList, int* sizeOfWords)
{
    //access thread id
    const unsigned int bid = blockIdx.x;
    const unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int index = bid * blockDim.x + tid;

    const char *current_word = &(*(d_wordList+(index*30)));
    for(int i=0; i<K; i++)
    {
        crc32 = update_crc(i, d_wordList+(index*30), sizeOfWords[index]);
        mapBloom(crc32);
    }

}

/*
    Main Function
*/

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;                  
    FILE *fp2;                  
    word32 i;

    cout<<"-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"--  Program to implement a general Bloom filter  --\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    //Determine number of bytes in Bloom Filter
    NumBytes = M/8;
    if((M%8)!=0)
    {
        cout<<"*** ERROR - M value must be dibisible by 8 \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Initialize the CRC32 table
    gen_crc_table();

    //Clear the Bloom filter
    for(i = 0; i<NumBytes; i++)
    {
        BFilter[i] = 0x00;
    }

    fp1 = fopen("word_list_10000.txt","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR in opening input file #1 ***\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    fp2 = fopen("bloom_query.txt","r");
    if(fp2 == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR in opening input file #2 ***\n";
        exit(1);
    }

     //determine the number of words in list: 

     std::ifstream f("word_list_10000.txt");
     std::istream_iterator<std::string> beg(f), end;
     int number_of_words = distance(beg,end);

     cout<<"Number of words in file: "<<number_of_words<<endl;
     cout<<"size of char: "<<sizeof(char)<<endl;

     cout<<"Reading to array!:  "<<endl;
     ifstream file("word_list_10000.txt");

     const int text_length = 30;

     char *wordList = new char[10000 * text_length];
     int *sizeOfWords = new int[10000];

     for(int i=0; i<number_of_words; i++)
     {
         file>>wordList + (i*text_length);
         sizeOfWords[i] = strlen(wordList + (i*text_length));
         cout<<wordList + (i*text_length)<<endl;
     }

      char *dev_wordList;
      char *dev_sizeOfWords;

      cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_wordList, 30*number_of_words*sizeof(char));
      cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_sizeOfWords, number_of_words * sizeof(char));
      cudaMemcpy(dev_wordList, wordList, 30 * number_of_words * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(dev_sizeOfWords, sizeOfWords, number_of_words * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    unsigned int crc_size = sizeof(word32) * 256;
    unsigned int bfilter_size = sizeof(char) * M/8;

    static word32* d_CrcTable;
    char* d_BFilter;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_CrcTable, crc_size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_BFilter, bfilter_size);

    //copy host arrays CrcTable & BFilter to device memory

    cudaMemcpy(d_CrcTable, CrcTable, crc_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_BFilter, BFilter, bfilter_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Setup execution parameters
    int n_blocks = (number_of_words + 255)/256;
    int threads_per_block = 256;

    dim3 grid(n_blocks, 1, 1);
    dim3 threads(threads_per_block, 1, 1);

    mapBloomKernel<<<grid, threads>>>(dev_wordList, sizeOfWords);

    fclose(fp1);

    //Output results header
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"Matching strings are...  \n";

    /*


    ...
    ...
    ...

    */

    fclose(fp2);
}



/*
 * Function to initialize CRC32 table
 */

void gen_crc_table(void)
{
    register word32 crc_accum;
    register word16 i, j;
    //Initialize the CRC32 8-bit look-up table
    for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        crc_accum = ((word32) i<<24);
        for(j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            if(crc_accum & 0x80000000L)
                crc_accum = (crc_accum << 1) ^POLYNOMIAL;
            else
                crc_accum = (crc_accum << 1);
        }
        CrcTable[i] = crc_accum;
        //cout<<CrcTable[i]<<endl;
    }
}

/*
 * Function to generate CRC32
 */

__device__ word32 update_crc(word32 crc_accum, char *data_blk_ptr, word32 data_blk_size)
{
    register word32 i, j;
    for(j=0; j<data_blk_size; j++)
    {
        i = ((int) (crc_accum >>24) ^ *data_blk_ptr++) & 0xFF;
        crc_accum = (crc_accum << 8) ^ CrcTable[i];
    }
    crc_accum = ~crc_accum;

    return crc_accum;
}

/*
 * Function to map hash into Bloom filter
 */

__device__ void mapBloom(word32 hash)
{
    int tempInt;
    int bitNum;
    int byteNum;
    unsigned char mapBit;
    tempInt = hash % M;
    byteNum = tempInt / 8;
    bitNum = tempInt % 8;

    mapBit = 0x80;
    mapBit = mapBit >> bitNum;

    //Map the bit into Bloom filter 
    BFilter[byteNum] = BFilter[byteNum] | mapBit;
}

/*
 * Function to test for a Bloom filter match
 */

__device__ int testBloom(word32 hash)
{
    int tempInt;
    int bitNum;
    int byteNum;
    unsigned char testBit;
    int retCode;
    tempInt = hash % M;
    byteNum = tempInt / 8;
    bitNum = tempInt % 8;

    testBit = 0x80;
    testBit = testBit >> bitNum;
    if (BFilter[byteNum] & testBit)
        retCode = 1;
    else
        retCode = 0;
    return retCode;
}
```

Command line used to compile:

```
/OUT:"E:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Work\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.2\Debug\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO
 /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\Win32" "cudart.lib" 
"kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib"
 "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST 
/ManifestFile:"Debug\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG 
/PDB:"E:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Work\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.2\Debug\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.pdb" 
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/PGD:"E:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Work\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.2\Debug\CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0.pgd" /TLBID:1 
/DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Full output:

```
7   IntelliSense: expected an expression e:\...\kernel.cu   145 18  CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0
    Error   6   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing 
Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --
cl-version 2010 -ccbin "F:\Installed\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
 GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing 
Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart 
static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  "
 -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj 
"E:\...\kernel.cu"" exited with code 2. C:\...\CUDA 5.5.targets 592 10  CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0
    Error   5   error : **External calls are not supported** (found non-inlined call to _Z10update_crcjPKcj)    E:\...\kernel.cu    40  1   CUDA_Bloom_filter_v0
```

Comment: Where's the function definition?

Comment: Actually, you can *only* call `__device__` functions from kernel functions (and other `__device__` functions). So the problem must be somewhere else. Which compute capability are you targetting?

Comment: I suspect (pre)Fermi versions..

Comment: My graphics card is gt330M, so I have compute capability 1.3. But I am running with default compute capability, 1.0

Comment: You should provide a complete code that reproduces the problem, as well as the command line used to compile, plus the full compiler output showing the exact error message. Also, gt 330m is compute capability 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is getting confused because your function prototype (forward declaration) looks like this:

```
__device__ word32 update_crc(word32 crc_accum, const char *data_ptr, word32 data_size);
```

but your definition is like this:

```
__device__ word32 update_crc(word32 crc_accum, char *data_blk_ptr, word32 data_blk_size)
{
```

Your function definition expects the second parameter to be of type `char *`.  But you are passing a `const char *` parameter (and your forward declaration is of type `const char *`).

This is a basic C/C++ coding error.

Your forward declaration should match your definition.  Since it did not, the compiler looked elsewhere for a matching function and could not find it.

The fix for this issue is to make your function definition match:

```
                                               add const here
                                               v
__device__ word32 update_crc(word32 crc_accum, const char *data_blk_ptr, word32 data_blk_size)
{
```

Note that when I compile your code with this fix, there are still some pretty important warnings:

```
t573.cu(73): warning: a __device__ variable "BFilter" cannot be directly written in a host function

t573.cu(185): warning: a __device__ variable "CrcTable" cannot be directly written in a host function
```

These should not be ignored.  For example, taking the first warning, you have this variable:

```
__device__ char BFilter[M / 8];         //Bloom filter array of M/8 bytes
```

You cannot write this variable directly in your host code (in `main`):

```
//Clear the Bloom filter
for(i = 0; i<NumBytes; i++)
{
    BFilter[i] = 0x00;
}
```

Instead use a function like [`cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#variable-type-qualifiers)